# como genero un toast para cada boton

Tags: javascript

como le puedo hacer para que en el mensaje del toast me genere el contenido que quiero. de acuerdo al boton donde haya pulsado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#snackbar {
    visibility: hidden;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-left: -125px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 16px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#snackbar.show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
    animation: fadein 0.5s, fadeout 0.5s 2.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;} 
    to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
    to {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;} 
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes fadeout {
    from {bottom: 30px; opacity: 1;}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 0;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Pruebas</h2>
<p>.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Boton azul</button>

   
<div id="snackbar">has pulsado el boton azul </div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar")
    x.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Estoy haciendo una consulta y entonces de acuerdo a la consulta me genera x botones. 
digamos que el primer boton se llama
1º Azul
2º verde
3º morado

si pulso en el boton azul
en el toast el mensaje me dira
has pulsado el boton azul
pero si pulso en el morado me sigue diciendo has pulsado el boton azul.

este es mi codigo Original que estoy usando.

---

```html
echo "<button class='w3-button' id='enviarProyecto' onclick='myFunction()'  >Enviar Proyecto </button>";
echo "<div id='snackbar'> Proyecto Enviado a @".$row['nombre']."</div>";


function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar")
    x.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
}
```

tiene que ver algo del Id, lo he pasado. pero me confundo.  porque no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Primero te falta un ; en la primera línea de la función.

Para hacer que la función pueda variar el comportamiento según el botón, agregale un parametro a la función que indique el snackbar a utilizar. Puede ser por ejemplo el id del snackbar correspondiente.

Y cambias la función para que levante el snackbar en base al parámetro.

```
function myFunction(snackbarId) {
    var x = document.getElementById(snackbarId);
    x.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function(){ x.className = x.className.replace("show", ""); }, 3000);
```

Luego en el html, agregas los diferentes snackbars con diferente `id`, y en el onclick agregas el `id` como parametro de la función.

```
<button onclick="myFunction('snack2')">Boton azul</button> 
<div id="snack2">has pulsado el boton azul </div>
```

}